# Short echo repurposed in newer versions of PHP?

Tags: php, php-shorttags

I have heard from several people that `<?=` has been re-purposed / replaced in newer versions of PHP, but am unable to find supporting documentation to this change, or to what version(s) it effects. Has `short echo` been replaced or re-purposed and is there supporting documentation to it?

Comment: Stop listening to those people

Comment: It is still available, can be used, works, you just have to enable it.

Comment: @arkascha actually, as of php 5.4, it is enabled by default. Prior to that you needed short_tags to be enabled. This is the only change I have seen to the short echo in recent years.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I was told as of 5.5 or 5.6 it worked but was ment for something else so there could be conflicts etc, I was never able to track down what this other architect ment though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current documentation does not reflect any change of behaviour of shorthand echo (`<?=`) since version 5.4.0, in which only the necessary configuration to enable it was changed.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php